# Web project installation on IIS

Tags: php, mysql, web, iis, connection

I would like to share with my project and get your opinions. I developed the project which needs to be launched through IIS. The problem is with linking to other pages. In fact, I partially managed to solve the problem, but so far by 30%. Authorization to the index.php main page is successful, but when you go to all other pages (for example, the "List of applications" page), error 404 appears.I send screenshots of the project. I can’t figure out why such an error comes out, I will be glad to hear your offers.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue try to follow some below steps:

1)make sure you installed php in iis.

2)Select site in ii manager and select directory browsing feature and enable it from the action pane.

[image]

3)after enabling it select site again and right-click on it and select Explore option and check that you are looking for file or folder is available or not.

[image]

and if you have .htaccess file and rewrite rules in it than install [URL rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module in iis and import the .htaccess file in iis URL rewrite.

4) make sure that your site folder has iis_iusr and iusr permission.

To import the .htaccess file in iis:

1)Select site in iis.

2) select url rewrite module.

3)select import rule from the action pane.

[image]

4)Copy-paste your .htaccess file or select it under “rewrite rules” or select .htaccess file from “Configuration file”.

[image]